# Retrieve a table with a Macro

Tags: macros, environments, counters

I would like to retrieve a table with a Command which is using an new environment including a table.
So basically something like:

```
\begin{measurtab}{Test 2110}
\value{0.0}{0.0}
\end{measuretab}
```

should bring up something like this:
[image: measuretab]

I have tried to do the following as a minimum example but I am struggling with the number of arguments and how to use counters properly. I am no TeXpert so I hope you can help me with what I am doing wrong.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, enumerate, verbatim, scrpage2, xcolor, array, graphicx, tabularx, wrapfig, booktabs}


\newcounter{measureNo}
\setcounter{measureNo}{1}
  \newcommand\messwert[1][\stepcounter{MessNr}]{\theMessNr & lol & lol}

\newenvironment{measuretab}[3]
  {\begin{tabularx}{|c|r|r|}
  \hline                        
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{THE TITLE}\\
  \hline
  \# & Zeit [ms] & Geschwindigkeit [\nicefrac{m}{s}]\\
  \hline
  }
{\end{tabularx}}

\begin{document}

\begin{measurtab}{Test 2110}
\value{0.0}{0.0}
\end{measuretab}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: It isn't at all clear from your question what is the connection between the input of  `\value{0.0}{0.0}`  and the  3 columns of 4 numbers that you show in the desired output?

Comment: also you clearly need `tabular` not `tabularx` in the above code (`tabularx` would require a different syntax and is anyway not suitable for numeric data)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\newcommand*{\initrowcounter}{%
    \newcounter{rowcounter}
    \setcounter{rowcounter}{0}
}

\newcommand*\addrow[2]{%
    \stepcounter{rowcounter}%
    \therowcounter & #1 & #2\\%
}

\begin{document}
\initrowcounter{}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|r|r|}
    \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{THE TITLE}\\
    \hline
        \# & Zeit [ms] & Geschwindigkeit [m/s]\\
    \hline
        \addrow{0.0}{0.0}
        \addrow{0.5}{0.7}
        \addrow{1.0}{1.2}
        \addrow{1.5}{2.1}
        \addrow{2.0}{2.5}
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```